# installing json-framework with iOS

Tags: ios, json, json-framework

This seems like a simple-stupid thing, but I can't get it to work.  Here's the flow:

Download and unzip the json-framework package from GitHub.
Create a new standard, Single View Application with XCode.
Make a new group named 'JSON' in my project.
Make a directory in my project directory named 'JSON', and copy the files from 'json-framework-master/Classes/*' into this directory.
In the XCode project, drag the files I just copied into the 'JSON' group I created.  The files are successfully added to the project.
In my code, I add at the top:

```
#include "SBJSON.h"
```

in the app delegate launch method, I add this:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hi" forKey:@"There"];
NSString *myString = [myDict JSONRepresentation];
```

This is just a simple test to make sure JSON is working correctly.
Everything builds and compiles fine, but I get this error:

```
-[__NSDictionaryI JSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d537b20
```

I even tried adding the '-all_load' linker flag to both the project and the target, but that does nothing.  I am building on an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.

Also I know that iOS5+ includes native JSON support, but I need to support older versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem was that XCode is not automatically adding the .m files to the list of Compile Sources.  I had to manually go into ->Targets->Build Phases->Compile Sources and manually add the .m file associated with JSON.

Seems like this shouldn't be the default.. maybe I accidentally set a config setting in XCode somewhere to make this the default behavior when adding files?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use JSONKit instead of SBJSon.

you should also try to work with Cocoapods for theses kind of dependencies, and setup issues